# Asp.Net MVC 2 Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to use validations with ASP.NET MVC 2.
I am just validating a textbox value.
Below is my approach.
Create View -:

```
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%> 
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class="input-standard"})%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) %>
```

Model Property-:

```
[Required (ErrorMessage="Name Required")]

public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

But if i keep the textbox empty and click on submit then still the ModelState.IsValidate prperty is returning true.

Please suggest what am i doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint before the `ModelState.IsValid` call to determine that the value is null or an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` and a reference to the Microsoft MVC ajax validation javascript (MicrosoftMvcAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcValidation.js).

Edit: sorry just noticed this does not answer your question :)

Comment: Yes...I have added <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %> and reference to MicrosoftMvc refrences too.